Base R shiny get values from radio group buttons
I am trying to recreate shinyWidgets::radioGroupInputs() using the Bootstrap Example, but I cannot read the values from shiny.
The base HTML code for the Bootstrap buttons is this
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>
</div>

when I take the basic shinyWidgets::radioGroupInputs() HTML output, it doesn't work, as the JS dependency (shinyWidgets-bindings.min.js) is not loaded.
One workaround that I found is to (ab-)use the the onclick of the buttons.
For example, to bind the above code to the id "ASD", we can use the following:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fluid(
shiny::HTML(r"{
<div class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container" role="group">
  <div class="shiny-options-group">
    <div class="btn-group" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="ASD" for="btnradio1" onclick="Shiny.setInputValue('ASD', 'btnradio1')">Radio 1</label>

      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="ASD" for="btnradio2" onclick="Shiny.setInputValue('ASD', 'btnradio2')">Radio 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    val <- input$ASD
    print(paste("ASD: ", val))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

This works, but feels a bit hackish and I cannot preselect a value (eg start with Radio 2 selected).
Is there a better way to retrieve the checked values from these radio group buttons?

I think this article might help you https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/html-ui/

Not sure how that helps me... The HTML code I have is valid HTML, it just doesnt want to communicate with shiny (shiny cannot pick up the reactive values)

If you want to recreate some inputs as stated, a better approach might be to create a custom input binding (see also here). In the below example I wrote the getValue method such that it will return the value attribute (similar used as described here).
Concerning your point that you cannot preselect a value notice that you can use the checked property. Below, I added this to the second button.

library(shiny)
library(bslib)


ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$script(
    type = "text/javascript",
    HTML(
      "const myCustomBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();",
      "$.extend(myCustomBinding, {
                find: function(scope) {
                    return $(scope).find('.form-group_shiny-input-checkboxgroup_shiny-input-container');
                },
                getValue: function(el) {
                    var value = $(el).find('.btn-check:checked').attr('value');
                    return value;
                },
                subscribe: function(el, callback) {
                    $(el).on('click button', function(e) {
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                receiveInputMessage: function(el, message) {
                },
                unsubscribe: function(el) {
                    $(el).off('myCustomBinding');
                }
            });",
      "Shiny.inputBindings.register(myCustomBinding);"
    )
  ),
  shiny::HTML(
    r"{
<div class="form-group_shiny-input-checkboxgroup_shiny-input-container" role="group" id="rg">
  <div class="shiny-options-group">
    <div class="btn-group" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" value = "val1">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="ASD" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>

      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off" value = "val2" checked>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="ASD" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}"
  ),
verbatimTextOutput("valOut")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$valOut <- renderPrint({
    val <- input$rg
    paste("ASD: ", val)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Using @Jan's wonderful answer, I created this generalization so that its easier to use.
library(shiny)
library(bslib)


radioGroupButtons <- function(inputId,
                              choices,
                              selected = NULL,
                              class = "btn-outline-primary",
                              style = "") {
  js <- r"{
  const radioGroupBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
  $.extend(radioGroupBinding, {
    find: function(scope) {
      return $(scope).find(".radio-group-buttons");
    },
    getValue: function(el) {
      var value = $(el).find(".btn-check:checked").attr("value");
      if (value === undefined) {
        return null;
      }
      return value;
    },
    subscribe: function(el, callback) {
      $(el).on("change.radio-group-buttons", function(e) {
        callback();
      });
    },
    unsubscribe: function(el) {
      $(el).off(".radio-group-buttons");
    },
    setValue: function(el, value) {
      $(el).find(".btn-check").prop("checked", false);
      if (value !== null)
        $(el).find('.btn-check[value="' + value + '"]').prop("checked", true);
    },
    receiveMessage: function(el, data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty("selected")) {
        this.setValue(el, data.selected);
      }
      if (data.hasOwnProperty("choice_names")) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.choice_values.length; i++) {
          $(el).find(".btn-check-label").eq(i).html(data.choice_names[i]);
        }
      }
      if (data.hasOwnProperty("choice_values")) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.choice_values.length; i++) {
          $(el).find(".btn-check").eq(i).attr("value", data.choice_values[i]);
        }
      }
      if (data.hasOwnProperty("disabled")) {
        $(el).find(".btn-check").prop("disabled", data.disabled);
      }
      $(el).trigger("change");
    },
  });
  Shiny.inputBindings.register(radioGroupBinding);
  }"

  labels <- if (is.null(names(choices))) choices else names(choices)
  classes <- if (length(class) < length(choices))
    rep(class, length(choices)) else class

  choices_ui <- lapply(
    seq_along(choices),
    function(i) {
      shiny::tagList(
        shiny::tags$input(
          type = "radio",
          class = "btn-check",
          name = inputId,
          id = paste0(inputId, i),
          value = choices[i]
        ),
        shiny::tags$label(
          class = paste("btn btn-check-label", classes[i]),
          id = paste0(inputId, i, "-label"),
          `for` = paste0(inputId, i),
          shiny::HTML(labels[i])
        )
      )
    }
  )
  if (!is.null(selected)) {
    i <- match(selected, choices)
    if (i > 0) {
      choices_ui[[i]][[1]] <- shiny::tagAppendAttributes(
        choices_ui[[i]][[1]],
        checked = NA
      )
    }
  }

  shiny::tagList(
    shiny::singleton(shiny::tags$script(shiny::HTML(js))),

    shiny::tags$div(
      class = paste(
        "radio-group-buttons",
        "form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container"
      ),
      role = "group",
      id = inputId,
      style = style,
      shiny::tags$div(
        class = "shiny-options-group",
        shiny::tags$div(

          class = "btn-group",
          role = "radiogroup",
          "aria-label" = "Basic radio toggle button group",
          choices_ui
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

#' @export
updateRadioGroupButtons <- function(session, inputId,
                                    selected = NULL,
                                    choices = NULL,
                                    choice_names = NULL,
                                    choice_values = NULL,
                                    disabled = NULL) {

  if (!is.null(choices)) {
    choice_values <- choices
    choice_names <- if (is.null(names(choices))) choices else names(choices)
  }

  message <- list(
    selected = selected,
    choice_values = choice_values,
    choice_names = choice_names,
    disabled = isTRUE(disabled)
  )
  message[sapply(message, is.null)] <- NULL
  session$sendInputMessage(inputId, message)
}


ui <- page_fluid(
  radioGroupButtons("rg",
                    c("A" = "a", "B" = "b", "C" = "c"),
                    selected = "b",
                    class = c("btn-outline-primary", "btn-outline-secondary", "btn-outline-success")),
  verbatimTextOutput("valOut")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$valOut <- renderPrint({
    val <- input$rg
    paste("ASD: ", val)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

